# Can my self published book on Amazon KDP, be distributed via other channels?

Tags: amazon, copyright, kdp, independent-publishing, printed

Only after self-publishing my book on Amazon KDP, I got to know that they do not provide print book option(i.e. paperback) in major countries where my readers are e.g. India.

Mainly they are providing print option only in US/UK/AUS. You might say that, even people from India can order from US/UK amazon. But it is impractical, the custom fee is more than the cost of the book. This has become a road blocker for me.

So what options do I have? Can I publish it on other platforms such as Flipkart(an e-commerce site similar to Amazon) or any local vendor who can help with print and distribute for the geographies Amazon print is not available. Any other suggestions to deal with this?

Answer (score 1):

> Yes, in most cases, you retain the rights to your self-published book,
> and you can choose to distribute it through other channels besides
> Amazon Kindle Direct Publishing (KDP). However, you should check the
> Terms and conditions of the specific publishing agreement you have
> with Amazon, as they may have exclusivity requirements.

- Amazon KDP Royalty Options:

Two royalty options are available: 70% and 35%.

**70% Royalty Option:**

- Requires enrollment in the KDP Select program.
- Exclusive distribution through the Kindle Store for 90 days.
- During this period, eBook cannot be available on other platforms.

**35% Royalty Option:**

- Offers more flexibility.
- Allows distribution through other channels without exclusivity
  requirements.

**Important Note:**
Terms and conditions may change, so it's crucial to stay updated.
Consider consulting with a legal professional for compliance with any policy updates.

> There are so many other platforms you can give a try

Answer (score 0):

Your the author/publisher of said book/eBook so you control where to market it, provided you follow the contract (i.e. KDP etc) you signed, so its beneficial to read the contract details. It might necessitate you cancelling off from one business program and jumping onto another business program that serves your purposes better. Read the contract details at IngramSpark; perhaps you'll find a better solution there. Considering the 1.4 billion people in India, it seems as if there must be some kind of global book/eBook market already covering that region effectively (other than just KDP).

For example from D2D:
[D2D info](https://draft2digital.com/faq/), skip down to where it talks about *"partner stores"*.
Quote:

> "...If you currently sell a print book with Amazon KDP Print Expanded Distribution or Ingram Spark, we do not recommend you list with D2D Print. If you currently list your books with KDP Print without Expanded Distribution (Expanded Distribution disabled), D2D Print will be a good fit to help expand your reach."

You want to avoid the duplication overlap where it might occur (whether book/ eBook). It all depends on the details of the contract you signed (at KDP etc).

KDP contract - read this:
[KDP contract info](https://kdp.amazon.com/en_US/help/topic/G200627430)

Jump down to KDP Select Program section:

> "While enrolled in KDP Select, your Digital Book must be exclusive to us...."

Note: **KDP Select** is the difference between their *35% royalty* and their *70% royalty* program.

An author/publisher will eventually make key changes in direction ... such as a switch from one book/eBook marketing platform to another that better serves their print and digital goals (i.e. we went from print to POD 10 year ago).